# Tkinter Entry Returns Default Value, Not Entered Value

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to have a button return whatever value I have entered in the Entry field, but it always returns the default value set within an XML file. The program seems to ignore what I have entered in the box when it reports the value.

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from formation import AppBuilder

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

app = AppBuilder(path="calculator.xml")

def calculate(event=None):
    # event parameter needs to be there because using the bind method passes an event object
    # access the expr_var we created earlier to determine the current expression entered
    expr = app.expr_var.get()

    # evaluate the expression
    try:
        result = expr
    except Exception:
        # if the expression entered was malformed and could not be evaluated
        # we will display an error message instead
        result = "Invalid expression"

    # display the result
    app.result.config(text=result)


app.connect_callbacks(globals())

app.mainloop()
```

This calls to an xml file with the following code:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<tkinter.Tk
    xmlns:attr="http://www.hoversetformationstudio.com/styles/" 
    xmlns:layout="http://www.hoversetformationstudio.com/layouts/" 
    name="tk_1" 
    attr:layout="place" 
    layout:width="300" 
    layout:height="233" 
    layout:x="30" 
    layout:y="30">
        <meth name="title">
        <arg value="title" />
        </meth>
        <meth name="geometry">
        <arg value="300x200+0+0" />
        </meth>
        <meta major="6" minor="2" name="version" />
    <tkinter.StringVar attr:name="expr_var" attr:value="" />
    <tkinter.Entry 
        name="entry_1" 
        attr:textvariable="expr_var"
        layout:width="200" 
        layout:height="25" 
        layout:x="50" 
        layout:y="35" 
        layout:bordermode="outside" />
    <tkinter.Label
        name="result" 
        layout:width="200" 
        layout:height="25" 
        layout:x="50" 
        layout:y="74" 
        layout:bordermode="outside" />
    <tkinter.Button name="calculate" attr:text="button_1" layout:width="80" layout:height="25" layout:x="110" layout:y="133" layout:bordermode="outside">
        <event sequence="&lt;Button-1&gt;" handler="calculate" add="False" />
    </tkinter.Button>
</tkinter.Tk>
```

I used FormationStudio to build the tkinter GUI.
I am not sure what I am doing wrong or if I should take a completely different approach.

Comment: It is because of multiple instances of `Tk()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because there are two instances of `Tk()`:

- the one you created explicitly
- the one `AppBuilder` created implicitly

Remove the instance created explicitly.

```py
from formation import AppBuilder

app = AppBuilder(path="calculator.xml")

def calculate(event=None):
    # event parameter needs to be there because using the bind method passes an event object
    # access the expr_var we created earlier to determine the current expression entered
    expr = app.expr_var.get()

    # evaluate the expression
    try:
        result = expr
    except Exception:
        # if the expression entered was malformed and could not be evaluated
        # we will display an error message instead
        result = "Invalid expression"

    # display the result
    app.result.config(text=result)


app.connect_callbacks(globals())

app.mainloop()
```

Comment: I tried that before but I get met with a Runtime Error saying "Too early to create variable: no default root window quoting the line >>> AppBuilder(path="calculator.xml")

Comment: It is fixed in latest version of `AppBuilder`.

Comment: I had to uninstall python and reinstall it as available to all users through the Windows Store. Not sure what the difference is but that seems to have worked. Thank you for your help!